# How do I make this kind of Query in Django foreign key relationships?

Tags: python, django, model

I have the following data model

Customers

Have many Addresses
Have many Credit cards

Given a credit card record, I want to be able find out all the addresses that I can apply against it.

Basically I want to be able to write a query like this...

```
SELECT address.line1, address.line2, address.city, 
address.state, address.zip FROM 
addresses, creditcards 
WHERE
addresses.custid = creditcards.custid and 
creditcard.number = 'Thenumber#'
```

I am fairly new to Django and I can only think of writing the code like this which I suspect wil fire 100s of queries.

```
for acard in creditcard.objects.filter(cardno = 'thenumber#'):
    for anaddress in Address.objects.filter(customer = acard.customer):
        print anaddress.list_values()
```

Is there a different design that I should adopt?  I cannot think of using ManyToMany here as it is technically not many to many?   am I thinking this wrong?

here is the model I had in mind...

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    pass

class creditcard(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)

class addresss(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    line1 = models.CharField()
    # etc., etc.,
```

Comment: Can you post your models.py for these models?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always start from the model you want to actually query. In this case, you want addresses, so you should start from there.

```
addresses = Address.objects.filter(customer__creditcard__number = 'thenumber#')
```

Comment: I have added the model.  If I understand what you are proposing you are "following the relationship backwards" is that right?

Comment: Yes. The backwards relation in the query syntax is just the lowercase name of the model (as opposed to the `foo_set` name used  in the attribute syntax).